# How to set QWebSocketServer disconnect time while not use for a long time？

Tags: qt

I'm using QWebSocketServer and QWebChannel for communicating between c++ and js.
No correspondence for about 30 minutes，the socket will be cloesd. There is a report,"CRITICAL,  WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state".
How can I set the time to 2 hours or more?

Comment: You should implement a 'ping' mechanism to keep the underlying TCP connection alive.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use  `QTimer` object.

In files:

.h

```
QTimer m_timeToDisconnect;//(better to be private)
```

.cpp

```
m_timeToDisconnect.setSingleShot(true);
m_timeToDisconnect.setTimerType(Qt::VeryCoarseTimer);
connect(m_pTcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &MySocket::getMessage);
connect(m_timeToDisconnect, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){m_pTcpSocket->close();});
```

when you get some data `&QTcpSocket::readyRead`, you should start Again Timer

```
m_timeToDisconnect.start(7200000)
```